# Core Data iPhone - Update on one table and delete from other table

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data

In my application, I have two entities in database. I have a fetchedresultscontroller which displays data from first entity. I have a checkbox on each row on which when I click, my first table in database gets updated and that item gets inserted into second table.

What I want to do now is, if I disable the checkbox, I want to delete that entry from second table. Any guesses? Here is my code.

```
        currentStatus=@"true";
        NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"xyz", @"name", @"id", nil];
        NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:currentStatus,name, id, nil]; 
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
        NSManagedObject *data;
        data = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SecondTable" inManagedObjectContext:[self context]];
        for(id key in dictionary) {
            [data setValue:[dictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:key];  
        }
```

I didnt find anything like 'deleteObjectforEntityForName'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this method in [NSManagedObjectContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSManagedObjectContext)?

```
- (void)deleteObject:(NSManagedObject *)object
```

Comment: I used it but it gets deleted from the same table. How can I give the entity name?

Comment: If it's deleting from the wrong table, then you're deleting the wrong object.

Comment: Yup. Maybe thats what is happening. Let me check why everything except delete is working. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

set a flag to see the value of the checkbox. And depending on this flag value delete the data from your second table.

Comment: IT doesn't work. Not so simple in this case. Every FetchedResultsController gets hooked to one tableview. I'm not able to access the second table from this context.